# If $U\subseteq V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$, then $\partial U \cap V =\partial\left(V\setminus U\right)\cap V$?

Tags: general-topology

Assume $U\subseteq V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$, both open, is then $\partial U \cap V =\partial\left(V\setminus U\right)\cap V$?

**Edit:**
What if $U, V$ also are simply connected?

Comment: Is this a problem from a book or otherwise? Do you know it is true from such an authority and are trying to prove it, or is this just a question you thought of and are not sure if it is true or not? Letting $U$ and $V$ be open real intervals is an easy example where it is true. You could try working with definitions such as $\partial U= \overline{U}\cap (U^\circ)^c$ and $V \setminus U=V \cap U^c$.

Comment: This statement is just something i thought of, thinking it might be true. In need it in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ though.

Answer (score 6):

Consider $U = B(0,1)$ and $V = \overline{B(0,2)}$. Now we have
$$\partial U \cap V = S(0,1)$$ 
but $$\partial (V \setminus U) \cap V = S(0,1) \cup S(0,2)$$
Here $\partial$ refers to the boundary, $B$ refers to an open ball, and $S$ is a sphere.

Comment: Is $S(0,2)\subseteq B(0,2)$? @Kayle of the Creeks

Comment: No. $B(0,2) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |x| < 2\}$ and $S(0,2) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |x| = 2\}$.

Comment: Then why $\partial (V \setminus U) \cap V = S(0,1) \cup S(0,2)$?

Comment: You are correct, I just noticed an error in my answer. But I can modify it.

Comment: But i assume $U$ and $V$ are open!

Comment: I didn't see the edit, I'll keep working on this.

Comment: The example will be fine once it's fixed. And it confirms the statement in question by providing an example that is easier to visualize or draw.

Comment: @KayleoftheCreeks How about if $U,V$ are simply connected also?

Comment: Any more assumptions?

Comment: $S(0,1)\subset V$? For the first example? It looks explicitly removed.

Comment: Well $x \in S(0,1) \implies |x| = 1 < 2 \implies |x| < 2 \implies x \in B(0,2)$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the second example. Where V is the ball with the closed inner ball removed. The unit sphere had been removed so it can't be in the intersection.

Comment: You are correct, the example was incorrect. I tried to make some modifications to the answer but I couldn't find any quick examples. So the case where $U,V$ are both open sets which are not the empty set or the whole space, then this conjecture might hold true!

Comment: @KayleoftheCreeks No, $\partial \emptyset=\emptyset$

Comment: I just checked and the internet agrees with you! I am stumped.